# Trying to move the calendar icon into a text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

[image: This is how it is now] I am trying to move the calendar icon into the text box, but I could not move it. Please help me pass through this. Thanks in advance. Below is the code I have in Default.aspx file:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
 <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="control-label">Date of Event:
 </asp:Label> 
                           </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                                <asp:Calendar ID="DateOfEventCalender" runat="server" Visible="False" OnSelectionChanged="DateOfEventCalender_SelectionChanged" CalendarLocation="Bottom"></asp:Calendar>
                                <div class="right-inner-addon">
                               <asp:LinkButton ID="Calendar2LinkButton" runat="server" CssClass="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" CausesValidation="false" onclick="Calendar2LinkButton_Click"></asp:LinkButton>                           
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="DateOfEventText" runat="server" CssClass="form-control calendarForm" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
protected void DateOfEventCalender_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateOfEventText.Text = DateOfEventCalender.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
        DateOfEventCalender.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void Calendar2LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateOfEventCalender.Visible = true;
    }
```

Site.css: I tried different classes and makes no difference.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.right-inner-addon i {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 479px) {
.right-inner-addon i {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 10px 12px ;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
.right-inner-addon i {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 10px 12px ;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the div holding the textbox and icon position:relative and assign the icon position:absolute, right: 0 or and also assign top: 5px or whatever suits your requirement. You could achieve this by assign classes with these properties or simply add inline.